# Pushing updates to a webpage using server-sent events

Tags: javascript, php, html, post, server-sent-events

I would like to post data to my PHP page and then have it update the HTML page. I followed [this](http://www.developerdrive.com/2012/03/pushing-updates-to-the-web-page-with-html5-server-sent-events/) example of using server-sent events to push updates to a webpage.
Here is what I have right now:

output.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id="serverData"></div>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

//check for browser support
if(typeof(EventSource)!=="undefined") {
    //create an object, passing it the name and location of the server side script
    var eSource = new EventSource("send_sse.php");
    //detect message receipt
    eSource.onmessage = function(event) {
        //write the received data to the page
        document.getElementById("serverData").innerHTML = event.data;
    };
}
else {
    document.getElementById("serverData").innerHTML="Whoops! Your browser doesn't receive server-sent events.";
}
</script>
</html>
```

send_sse.php:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
$val = 0;
if (isset($_POST['msg'])){
    $val = $_POST['msg'];
}
echo "data: $val\n\n";
ob_flush();
?>
```

form.html:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="send_sse.php" method="post">
Message: <input type="text" name="msg"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that when the form posts the value, it does not update the output.html. It does output "0" and will update whenever I manually change the value of $val and save the file. However, I want the value of $val to be determined outside of the PHP file. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having here is that you have missed how SSE conceptually work. Your `output.html` page is making a GET request to your web server and executing the script `send_sse.php` and opening up a connection and **HOLDING** that connection open and waiting for updates.

When you are posting from `form.html` you are sending a POST request to your web server and executing the script `send_sse.php` on a completely **different** thread.

As you have not implemented any shared persistence between these two threads it will make no difference.

So to do what you want to do you will need to have code in `send_sse.php` that has some form of global persistence (e.g. database) and can detect new data and then flush that down to the browser.

I am not a PHP expert, but I have written [an example](http://bayn.es/real-time-web-applications-with-server-sent-events-pt-1/) in Node JS that uses REDIS pub/sub to provide said persistence.

I hope that helps.

Comment: This was helpful in letting me find the complete solution. However, I can't fully recall at the moment what the full solution turned out to be haha. I'll accept this as the answer though.